Acumatica - Get the Reference number of a File Uploaded
I'm trying to get the Reference number of a file
Right now Im creating a customization screen. one of the requirements is to show the reference number related to the file uploaded in the grid.
I tried using the PXRefNoteAttribute. but Im still trying to figure out how to implement it
Update: I Found a solution using EntityHelper class 'GetEntityRowID' I switched the separator to NULL which pulls the reference number.

Are you looking for the GUID for the specific file?
Typically, the notes and the files will link to the main record by the Note ID of that record, then there are a couple more GUIDs in the File tables (UploadFile and UploadFileRevision). Below is the example of how to get from InventoryItem all the way to the File Revisions.
select InventoryItem.InventoryCD, InventoryItem.NoteID, Note.NoteID,
NoteDoc.FileID,UploadFile.FileID,UploadFile.Name, UploadFileRevision.FileID,UploadFileRevision.FileRevisionID,UploadFileRevision.Data  
from InventoryItem
left join Note on InventoryItem.CompanyID=Note.CompanyID and InventoryItem.NoteID=Note.NoteID
left join NoteDoc on NoteDoc.CompanyID=Note.CompanyID and NoteDoc.NoteID=Note.NoteID
left join UploadFile on UploadFile.CompanyID=NoteDoc.CompanyID and UploadFile.FileID=NoteDoc.FileID
left join UploadFileRevision on UploadFileRevision.CompanyID=UploadFile.CompanyID and UploadFile.FileID=UploadFileRevision.FileID
where InventoryCD like '%WIDGET02  %'

And you will get something like below as the result


But Im trying to get the reference number of a file uploaded from multiple tables. I'm leaning towards on creating a query that links with all of the transaction screens that the client use but I think that can make the process slow.
